# Unable to map all paths to URIs in GetDefaultData Core Service call

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am getting an error while calling `GetDefaultData();`

```cs
(ComponentData)coreUtility.GetDefaultData(
                                        TridionProxy.CoreService.ItemType.Component, 
                                        componentEntity.FolderWebDavUrl );
```

There Error is:

> Unable to map all path to URIs.

The linked Schema is already mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

It means that your WebDAV url is not correct. It's trying to convert your WebDAV url into TcmUri and fails. Try reading the folder with your webdav url, to see if it's correct. Otherwise just read the folder and check `.LocationInfo.WebDavUrl` property.

P.S. Next time, please include complete error log message and StackTrace from Tridion event log

Comment: I still don't see a stack trace.

Comment: @Quirijn correct, that what he says, try to find it :)

Comment: sorry by mistake added comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot , you gave me direction to solve issue. Issue was in path, path contained slash at the end.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, then please accept it